# basic trigonometric equation query

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

I know that for the delta Dirac function the following **property** holds true: 
$δ(at)=\frac1{|a|}δ(t)$. Can i generalize that for any function:$f(at)=\frac1{|a|}f(t)$ ?

The equation i want to test it against is: $sin\big(2x+\fracπ4\big) = \frac12$. I solve below this equation using the above **property** and without using it.

- solution **without using** the property: $f(at)=\frac{1}{|a|}f(t)$
  $$
  \begin{align}
  sin\big(2x+\fracπ4\big) &= \frac12 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, <=>\\
  sin\big(2x+\fracπ4\big) &= sin\Big(\fracπ6\Big) <=> \\
  \Big\{_{2x+\fracπ4 =\, 2kπ+π-\fracπ6}^{2x+\fracπ4 =\,2kπ+\fracπ6}=>
  \Big\{_{x=kπ+\frac{7π}{24}}^{x = kπ-\frac{π}{24}}\,\,\,, \small{k=integer}
  \end{align}
  $$
- solution **using** the property: $f(at)=\frac{1}{|a|}f(t)$

$$
\begin{align}
sin\big(2x+\fracπ4\big) &= \frac12 \\
sin\big( \, 2(x+\fracπ8) \,\big) &= \frac12 \\
\frac12sin\big(x+\fracπ8\big) &= \frac12 \,\,(just\,used\,the\,property)\\
sin\big(x+\fracπ8\big) &= 1 \\
sin\big(x+\fracπ8\big) &= sin(\fracπ2) <=>\\
x+\fracπ8 &= 2kπ+\fracπ2 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=>\,\,\,x =  2kπ+\frac{3π}{8}\\
or\\
x+\fracπ8 &= 2kπ+π-\fracπ2 =>\,x =  2kπ+\frac{3π}{8}\\
\end{align}
$$

**If** the **property** $f(at)=\frac1{|a|}f(t)$ holds true, then why it does not work in the calculations(when i use that property), what kind of knowledge am i missing? What am i doing wrong? Can you propose a solution(if any for the second solution where i am using the property)?

Answer (score 1):

In general the property $f(at)=\frac1{|a|}f(t)$ does not hold true !

Counterexample: $f(t)=t^2$ or $f(t)=e^t$, etc ....